# How to overide a specific style when changing the screens resolution

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have this styling to an elenemt:

```
.width {
    width: 1024px !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I want to disable the "width" completely **OR** change it to this:

```
@media (max-width: 1280px){
    .width {
        min-width: 100% !important;
    }
```

When I run it like this, although I switch the screen resolution, it still uses the global style.

I prefer disabling it though.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the important statements from BOTH queries...it should be necessary anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to get a jsfiddle with your code ?
Do you fix your viewport width ? If yes, is it on the ddevice-width, screen-width, ou width ? Can I see your viewport meta tag ?

Comment: @Paulie_D - It is necessary for me. (in this case). 
Nono - No, I can't :(

Comment: Do you fix your viewport width ? If yes, is it on the device-width, screen-width, or width ? Can I see your viewport meta tag ?

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: @Nono meta viewport tag has nothing to do with this

Comment: Is it a typo or did you actually miss the closing `}` in the media query?

Comment: no, It's just here, on my code it's ok. 

I removed the !important just for testing and strangely it's still not working while other thing ARE working :S. 
what can the problem be? 

will it help if I'll past the CSS code here?

Comment: @Mr. Alien I thought it could have something with a fixed size for the viewport width but no. My bad

Comment: @Hatul recreate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the width then do

```
@media (max-width: 1280px){
    .width {
        width: auto !important;
    }
}
```

I would suggest removing the `!important` from both places

```
.width {
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 1280px){
    .width {
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

In your original code, there is a missing `}` not sure if it is a typo or not

If you want `min-width` then do, assuming you removed the `!important`. But you can just set `width: 100%` and there is no need to do `min-width`

```
@media (max-width: 1280px){
    .width {
        width: auto;
        min-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this in a browser and resize the window to see the changes... hope this help you!!!

**The HTML**

```
<div class="width">test</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.width{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:0 auto;
 }
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px){
 .width{
  width:1024px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
}
```